# orphanRemoval not working when one-to-many is the owning side?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities:

```
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "parentID")
    private Long parentID; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> childs;
}

public class Child {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentID", referencedColumnName = "parentID")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

I tried to remove the parent and I got an error message about the FK in the child if I understand it correctly it was because the child was the **owner**.

I then changed it to the following to make Parent the owner:

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "parentID")
private Set<Child> childs;
```

When I remove the parent hibernate does an update:

```
update child set parentID=null where parentID=?
```

But the Child still exists in the database, with the parentID as null. I thought orphanRemoval would solve this but it does not. Why is that?

(It is not possible to change the underlying database structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Child entity had more dependencies that needed bidirectional relationships.

Comment: And what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

```
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> childs;
}

public class Child {    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentID", referencedColumnName = "parentID")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Comment: It will not work because the child is then the owner.